# Read arraylist object value one by one only when click android button

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I have an ArrayList (studentName, Marks1, Marks2) like bellow 
bellow code is part of my whole code, so please don't confused yourself. I try to make it clear you as much as I can.

Please remember, after every click the it will go out of the function.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
ArrayList<allStudents> Student = new ArrayList(allStudents );
allStudents.add(new Student("A", 80, 94));
allStudents.add(new Student("B", 98, 91));
allStudents.add(new Student("F", 70, 84));
allStudents.add(new Student("C", 98, 92));
allStudents.add(new Student("H", 99, 93));

Collections.Student, new Comparator<allStudents>() {
@Override
public int compare(allStudents lhs, allStudents  rhs) {
return (rhs.getMakrs1() - lhs.getMakrs2());
}
});
}
```

Question 1. How can I set a button click event; so that when only I click a button it will read the first top then in next click it will read the 2nd top and then in 3rd click it read 3rd top and so on ?
and when all value will finish reading it will  to to Q2 (below), then start from Q1 again ?
Question 2. how can I sort/compare and get H on top then C on 2nd top and then B on 3rd top and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter variable to keep track of where you are in your `ArrayList`. Once you've extracted all the students, comparing them is a simple matter of accessing that second property (or whatever property you want to compare them by, but it seems as if that's it) like `Student.2property` and comparing and rearranging them. 
If you plan to insert them into a new `ArrayList`, it might also be helpful here to keep track of which one is the largest using a temporary variable (`Student temp = new Student`) and the making that the biggest variable you have left.

Comment: Let me know if you want more concrete code examples.

Comment: I m using that code for compare already. whts is necessary modification of that for compare both attributes? it will be difficult for my code, if I change the structure of the code. can u plz write the code ?

Answer (score 0):

its really simple. Use a counter variable.

```
int counter = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Student stud = allStudents.get(counter);//this gives you the position you want
        counter++; // in next click get another element
        if(counter>allStudents.size()){ 
        counter  = 0;//reset counter
        //for sorting elements use Collections.sort() method
        // as for the q2 part please try Collections.sort() reverse order

    }
    }
});
```

For sorting  Collections.sort() reverse order. A sample can be done like this:

```
 // create comparator for reverse order
  Comparator cmp = Collections.reverseOrder();  
  // note that I used reverseOrder because your data seemed to be best dealt this way.
  // sort the list
  Collections.sort(allStudents, cmp);
```

Comment: Yup, you are right ! How come, I could not remember that :(
anyways, if u plz take a look on Q2, then I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Value can be any order. question is if I have to compare two attributes ?
I m using that code for compare already. whts is necessary modification of that for compare both attributes? it will be difficult for my code, if I change the structure of the code. can u plz write the code ?

Comment: @user3740362 I have provided you with enough hints and even a preety close answer. The thing is you need to do something on your own too. You can swap the values of your arraylist using this code:Collections.swap(allStudents, postionFrom, positionTo); and I am not writing any more code for you. If this offends you I am sorry

Comment: its ok!the thing is wht u wrote, is already written (collection and comparator) in my code. so I want to know, how can I modify this. hope u get me now